# Incomplete or broken lines in Line Graph in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, linegraph

[How can I complete the broken lines in Line Graph in SSRS?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJshg.png)
I set the EmptyPoint to be ZERO but the lines are not there? Any solution is highly appreciated.

Development Tool: Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your field value to zero if it is nothing.

[image]

Set the following expression:

```
=iif(isnothing(Sum(Fields!Value.Value)),0,sum(Fields!Value.Value))
```

With the expression it will preview this:

[image]

Without the expression:

[image]

Let me know if this could help you.